# jaxrs override ContextResolver Provider

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jackson, jax-rs

I'm using `openapi generator` to generate some template code for me, the generated code also include a default Jackson ObjectMapper.

here is the code of the generated provider

```
package xxx.gen.invoker;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;

import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import java.io.IOException;

@Provider
public class JacksonConfig implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public JacksonConfig() throws Exception {

        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
            .setDateFormat(new RFC3339DateFormat());
    }

    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> arg0) {
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

Basically, **I don't want to modify the generated code**, is there any way I can create my own one with higher priority that can override the generated one?

I tried to write my customized one, but it seems that the generated one was picked up during runtime, so what's the resolution progress looks like when JAX RS pick up providers when there're multiple?

here is the code for my own customized provider

```
package xxx.service.util;

import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;


@Provider
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        this.mapper = createObjectMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }

    private ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the `@Priority` annotation?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha just tried, but not working even with `Integer.MAX_VALUE` priority

Comment: I think the lower the higher precedence

Comment: Yes you have to choose lower value to achieve higher priority. Default is USER_Priority wich means 5000.